# PHP: Using scandir bu excluding ../ ./ in the result

Tags: php, php-5.6

I'm using scandir and a foreach loop to display a list of files in a directory to the user. My code is below:

```
        $dir = scandir('/user1/caravans/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files');

        foreach($dir as $directory)
{
        echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=\"File[]\" value='$directory'/>$directory<br>";
        }
```

The problem is the script also echos a "." and a ".." (without the speech marks), is there an elegant way to remove these? Short or a regular expression. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) if the directory is `.` or `..` I recommend to take a look at the control structures [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

```
$dir = scandir('/user1/caravans/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files');

foreach($dir as $directory) {
    if( $directory == '.' || $directory == '..' ) {
        // directory is . or ..
        // continue will directly move on with the next value in $directory
        continue;
    }

    echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=\"File[]\" value='$directory'/>$directory<br>";
}
```

Instead of this:

```
if( $directory == '.' || $directory == '..' ) {
    // directory is . or ..
    // continue will directly move on with the next value in $directory
    continue;
}
```

you can use a short version of it:

```
if( $directory == '.' || $directory == '..' ) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that's a very useful way of filter in a loop

Comment: While this is a good answer, please format it so that newcomers understand that the continue is within the if(), while the echo is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate these directories with `array_diff`:

```
$dir = scandir($path);
$dir = array_diff($dir, array('.', '..'));
foreach($dir as $entry) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, in addition to swidmann's answer, is to simply remove '.' and '..' before iterating over them.

Adapted from http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#107215

```php
$path    = '/user1/caravans/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files';
$exclude = ['.', '..'];
$dir     = array_diff(scandir($path), $exclude);

foreach ($dir as $directory) {
    // ...
}
```

That way you can also easily add other directories and files to the excluded list should the need arise in the future.